# PHP - Submit data enum combine a button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, enums

I have an error when submit the data.
This is my controllers.

```
$data5['nisn']=$_POST['nisn'];
    $data5['status']=$_POST['submit'];
    $data5['status']=$status; //status is enum field ('belum tervalidasi','tervalidasi')
    $result=$this->m_peserta->insert_pendaftaran($data5);
```

My models

```
public function insert_pendaftaran($data5){
    $result=$this->db->insert("siswa",$data5);
    return $result;
}
```

My views

```
<button class="ui blue submit button" name="submit" formaction="<?php echo site_url('/admin/c_peserta/peserta_simpan');?>">Simpan</button>
```

The error message is

`"Undefined variable: status" and "Column 'status' cannot be null"`

Answer (score 0):

The error causing line seems to be `$data5['status']=$status;`.

`$status` is null at the time it is assigned to `$data5['status']`. So make sure to assign a proper value to the variable `$status` before assign it to any other variable or property.